# Is there a way to redistribute persisted dataset replication?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a persisted dataset MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, i use the replication factor to avoid issues when a specific node dies.
When the node dies my cluster manager automatically spawns a new node but the persisted dataset is not replicated into it.
I wanted to know if there is a way to tell a dataset to re-evaluate the block replication without having to unpersist and persist again

spark 2.3 running on Yarn